Determining sign change of a function using the first derivative test
Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function. Let $ f(x_0)= 0 $ at a point $ x_0 $. Suppose $ f’(x_0) = +ve $ and well defined.
Then, (1): is it always the case $f(x)$ change its sign from negative to positive at $ x_0 $?
Using mean value Theorem I can prove that if $f(x)$ changes its sign from negative to positive in an interval $[a, b ]$then there exists $x_0 \in [a, b ]$ such that $ f(x_0)= 0 $. But how can I prove or disprove (1)?

A continuous function is not necessarily differentiable. So $f'(x_0)$ is not necessarily well-defined. Moreover, what is $+ve$? Most probably just a positive value? In that case, just assume the opposite of (1) and show that the derivative (use the definition) is negative.

If $ f’(x_0)$ is well defined the (1) would always be true?

Found an answer saying that "if $f$ is differentiable at a limit point $x_0$ with positive derivative $f'(x_0) > 0$, then there exists a small neighborhood to the right of $x_0$ that all have higher function value than $f(x_0)$". That question was asking about something else.

The answer linked by @peterwhy gives a more general result and applying it with condition $f(x_0)=0$ proves your statement (1). Key idea of proof is the limit definition of derivative and the idea that if limit of "something" is positive then that "something" is positive in a neighborhood of point under consideration. Replace "something" by "difference quotient" now.

Perhaps a better way to edit the post to deal with cases were the derivative doesn't exist would be to just say "Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable" or "Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable and $x_0$".

Suppose $f(x_0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x_0 + h) -f(x_0)}h= k > 0$.
The definition of limits means: for every $ \epsilon > 0$ there exists and $\delta$ so that whenever $|h-0|< \delta$  we have $|\frac {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h - k| < \epsilon$.
Or in other words if we have $-\delta < h <\delta; h\ne 0$ we will have
$-\epsilon < \frac {f(x_0 + h)-f(x_0)}h -k< \epsilon$.
$ k-\epsilon < \frac {f(x_0 + h) -f(x_0)}h < k+\epsilon$.
But that is true for any $\epsilon > 0$ so let's pick an $\epsilon > 0$ where $k > \epsilon$.
Then we will have $0 < k-\epsilon < \frac {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h< k+\epsilon$.
And as $f(x_0) = 0$ that means....
For any $h: -\delta < h < \delta; h \ne 0$ then $\frac {f(x_0+h)}h$ is always positive!
And that does it.
If $x_0 - \delta < w < x_0$ and we let $h = w-x_0$ then $-\delta < h < 0$ and $w= x_0 + h$ and we have $\frac {f(x_0+h)}h = \frac {f(w)}h$ is positive. But $h$ is negative so $f(w)$ is negative.
If if $x_0 < y < x_0 + \delta$ and we let $h = y-x_0$ then $0 < h < \delta$ and $y = x_0+h$ and we have $\frac {f(x_0+h)}h=\frac {f(y)}h$ is positive. But $h$ is positive so $f(y)$ is positive.
And that's it from the very definition of derivative and the very definition of limits.

Yes, the answer is already implied in your question. There is no change in the sign of the second derivative as the x-axis is crossed without a criticality.
$ f’(x_0 + \epsilon) = +ve, f(x_0 + \epsilon) = +ve $ well defined with continuous derivatives.
$ f’(x_0 - \epsilon) = +ve, f(x_0 + \epsilon) = -ve $ well defined with continuous derivatives.
$ f’(x_0 +0) = +ve, f(x_0 + \epsilon) = 0 $ well defined with continuous derivatives.

The result holds without continuous derivatives. One just needs to apply the definition of derivative at a point.
